# Playing a simulation in fast-forward

Tags: optimization, simulation

I am working a simple game where users create structures in a sector, which is a 10x10 grid.  Some structures generate resources and some consume resources.  The sector itself might contain some resources outside of any structure.  The generators and consumers are related.  For example, a well might be generating water, then an splitter be consuming water and making hydrogen and oxygen, while a refinery is consuming hydrogen and oxygen and making rocket fuel, etc.

The rate at which they generate or consume resources can vary by structure - I call this the tick rate.  Each time a consumer ticks, it will first attempt to extract those resources from the structures that surround it in the sector.  If there are not enough, it will try to get them from the sector's storage.  If it is still not enough, the structure will stop.  Structures hold the resources that they generate up to some maximum.  Once they are full, they will not generate more until some are consumed.  If a structure is stopped, it will also not generate more resources, but the resources it already has can still be used by another adjacent structure.

It is not uncommon that there are patterns.  For example, if the well is very slow, the splitter will turn off when the well runs out of water, and then the refinery will turn off when the splitter runs out of gases.  Then when the well generates again, everything will turn back on.

When the user is playing a sector, I tick the sector continuously at the resolution of shortest tick rate of the sector's structures.  This works fine.  The pseudo-code looks like this:

```
const numTicks = (Date.now() - lastTickTime) / shortestTickTime;
let currentTickTime = lastTickTime;
for (i = 0; i < numTicks; i++) {
    currentTickTime += shortestTickTime;
    // check the consumers - all structures that are consumers
    for (curConsumer of consumers) {
       if (curConsumer.isRunning && 
           (currentTickTime - curConsumer.lastTickTime >= curConsumer.tickRate) {
           ... check surrounding structures for resources
           if (curConsumer.stillNeedsResources) {
               ... check sector for researches
           }
           if (curConsumer.stillNeedsResources) {
              ... no resources available
              curConsumer.isRunning = false;
           }
        }
        // check the generators - all structures that are generators
        for (curGenerator of generators) {
           if (curGenerator.isRunning && 
               (currentTickTime - curGenerator.lastTickTime >= curGenerator.tickRate) {
               ... add the generated resources
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am dealing with the case of a user coming back to a sector after a long absence - say, a few days - when hundreds or thousands of ticks have passed.  If I just naively try to play all of the ticks, it can take several seconds or several minutes to complete.

I am wondering if there are any tips or tricks for simulations of this kind for computing the net change without playing each tick.  Or, alternately, if there are changes I can make to the simulation to make this easier to compute.  Thanks!

Comment: This is not trivial *at all*, but you should be able to do better than a naive playback of the simulation horizon. You might want to look into an event-based simulation for the times when no user is active, which should drastically reduce the amount of computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1: Convert the raw data into "graph of nodes" form**, where each node represents a machine, and producers are at the bottom and consumers are at the top. For example it might look like:

```
          |
        (fuel)
          |
       Refinery
        /   \
       /     \
(hydrogen) (oxygen)
       \     /
        \   /
       Splitter
          |
       (water)
          |
         well
```

Note: If a machine has an output buffer (or input buffer/s); then those buffers should be separate nodes. For example, if everything has output buffers it might look like this:

```
          |
        (fuel)
          |
  Refinery output buffer
          |
        (fuel)
          |
       Refinery
        /   \
       /     \
(hydrogen) (oxygen)
    |         |
 Hydrogen   Oxygen
  output    output
  buffer    buffer
    |         |
(hydrogen) (oxygen)
       \     /
        \   /
       Splitter
          |
       (water)
          |
   Well output buffer
          |
       (water)
          |
         well
```

**Step 2: Determine "current steady state average rates"** by (initially) working from bottom up (producers to consumers). For example, if a well produces 1 unit of water every 4 ticks then assume it does produce an average of 0.25 water per tick; and if a splitter can convert 1 unit of water into 2 units of hydrogen and 1 unit of oxygen every 3 ticks then that's a max. rate of 0.333 water converted to 0.666 hydrogen and 0.333 oxygen, but you already know the well isn't producing water fast enough and can determine that the splitter will actually consume 0.25 water to produce 0.5 hydrogen and 0.25 oxygen.

Note that if a producer overproduces you will need to backtrack. For example, if a well produces 1 unit of water every 2 ticks then you'd assume it does produce an average of 0.5 water per tick; and if a splitter can convert 1 unit of water into 2 units of hydrogen and 1 unit of oxygen every 3 ticks then you know the well is producing more water than the splitter can consume and have to go back to the well and clamp its output to 0.333 water per tick.

**Step 3: Determine when (how many ticks) until the next thing happens** that will change the "current steady state average rates". If a resource can become depleted (e.g. the well runs dry) you need to know when that will happen. In the same way, if a "storage vessel" (an output buffer, input buffer, water tank, fuel storage chest, ...) becomes full or empty then you need to know when that will happen too. This is all based on the "current steady state average rates" you have - e.g. if a well's output buffer is empty and gains water (from well) at a rate of 0.5 water per tick and loses water (to splitter) at a rate of 0.33 water per tick; then you can calculate that the quantity it is storing increases at a rate of "0.5 - 0.33 = 0.17 per tick" and (combined with the buffer's capacity) calculate when the output buffer will become full.

Note that "how many ticks until the next thing happens" must also be limited to when you want to stop simulating.

**Step 4: Advance time up until the next thing that happens.** This mostly means updating the amount of stuff stored in "storage vessels" using the "current steady state average rates" you have; and then modifying any information (e.g. setting a well to "not functioning, ran dry").

**Step 5: Repeat the previous steps until you reach the time you want.** This is just "`if(current_time < stop_time) goto step 2`".

**Step 6: Update the world with the final state of everything.** This is mostly the reverse of step 1 - setting quantities in "storage vessels", marking resources as depleted, etc.

**Notes:**

- You might need to add "transport" as a type of node. For example, if you have conveyor belts taking water from the well to the splitter then that can be simulated like a "storage vessel" but with lag time (e.g. if belt was empty and items start being put on the belt, then it's going to take "length * speed" time before items arrive at the other end).
- If you want; you could add "breakdown" to the game (e.g. maybe there's a small chance that a splitter malfunctions and needs to be repaired). This is just an extra thing to take into account at step 3.
- Don't forget that you can modify the game design to make it easier. For a start, I would avoid feedback loops (e.g. if the fuel from the reactor is fed into a generator to create power that is consumed by a splitter that ...) because this makes everything significantly harder. I'd also be tempted to avoid "variable speed" things (e.g. miners travelling between an ore field and a drop off point, where the distance the miners travel increases as closer parts of the ore field are consumed so the "average ore per tick" is increasing and never constant).
- Don't forget that it's a game - it doesn't have to be 100% perfectly accurate, and only needs to be convincing enough to fool the player. If it's "slightly wrong" (e.g. an output buffer should have 23 items but only has 21 itmes) it's likely that nobody will ever notice.
- Depending on other details; you might (or might not) consider stopping early and switching to "simulate one tick at a time". For example, if you need to simulate 12345600 ticks, then you could use the approach I've described for the first 12345500 ticks, then use the approach you already have to do the last 100 ticks. This can help to make some things (e.g. position of items on a conveyor belt) seem a lot more realistic.

Comment: Wow, this is a huge help!  Converting into a graph and computing the effective flow and the time to next event was very helpful.  Also - step 6 - so glad you mentioned this as I noticed that I was updating some of the objects after each tick.  I was already avoiding feedback loops but the other tips are also helpful.  Just tested an initial rewrite and the time for 100,000 ticks is down from almost 55,000 ms to under 80!  Wow!